# Subjective perceptions at work

Tags: communication

I find it very important to behave professionally in the workplace. I want to help people, support them whenever that's possible.

But even with the best efforts, it's not possible for it to work always. There will always be somebody who hates you for no fault of yours or who has had a very bad day and wants everybody to know it.

Imagine you write a friendly, professional email to somebody and this somebody feels offended for some reason and escalates it to your boss.

My boss attaches a lot of attention to people's feelings, so the answer is always something like: "[your offended colleague's] truth is her truth", "perception is reality" and "I have to respect it". There's no support for me, just always for the person escalating.

In the case of some good bosses I had before, I felt we played in the same team. During escalations, I clarified the situation including sharing the facts and the written communication if applicable and shared how I was planning to address it. I felt that if I behaved correctly I had my boss's backing.

Of course, even if I did nothing wrong, there's a question about how to make it work with the person who for whatever reason was angry, but that's obvious and I have no problem with that. What I do have a problem with is my boss's interpretation that somebody being angry with me means it's my fault.

Is there a way to address it?

Comment: It's hard to address it in the correct way without more info. Can you elaborate a little bit on the context of the email that you sent to your coworker ? Did you simply ask her for some work-related info about the project, and she thought you were being bossy or implying that she did not do a good job ? Or did you make a friendly joke, and she was offended because she came from a different culture or different social background where that joke is not appreciated (and you may not be aware of that fact and did not intend to offend her) ?

Comment: But it may be your fault, be open minded to their position when you try to evaluate

Answer (score 1):

"Gee, sorry, I can see why you'd interpret it that way but that *really* wasn't my intent. Thanks for pointing it out, though, so I know what to avoid in the future."

An honest apology goes a very long way, and costs you nothing. Whether you think you did anything that should be apologized for or not, *something* set them off. If you don't want it to happen again, learn what their issue is and make the minor effort to avoid it.

Someone was asking for examples of "soft skills" recently. Being able to find ways to work with people you don't like is a perfect example. It isn't about who's right. It's about getting the job done.

Comment: I'm not sure why I should apologize to a bully. I did nothing wrong.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Defusing the situation is the best way to prevent repetition.

Comment: @christmasmonkey - You don’t provide any examples of what you said that offended the other individual. Therefore you must accept you likely can equally be viewed as the bully. Apologizing for offending someone is a correct course of action

Comment: And it may be pure misunderstanding. You lose nothing by accepting that.

Answer (score 0):

I read over and over and I do not draw your same conclusion that the lady being angry at you is judged by your boss as your fault.

"Coworker's truth is her truth and I have to respect it", just means he has to try and understand it from her side and not just dismiss it.

Your boss appears to be attempting to help you see the same thing. Your coworker appears to keep reporting you, boss has to listen, and you are not in trouble. Your boss is likely as aghast with it all as you are.

Sure you can fight with your boss - my truth is reality too, etc., but then you both become a problem.

Just keep doing what you do professionally and let her keep reporting, keep the evidence flowing but keep being in control, mild, etc.. Eventually they will have to talk to her.

If you do need to talk to the boss for real, try a different approach. Ask the boss what you should do the next time xyz happens, then follow his recommendation exactly. When the complaint comes with his exact method you then change it from a complaint about you to a complaint about both of you, which may get his action.

Comment: If a specific coworker continues to complain about words you say, the problem might be them, but unless your willing to accept it might be you it will continue to happened and eventually you will probably be held responsible for your comments. Try and simply not making those comments to this individual.

Comment: Yeah should have clarified the intention of my "if you really must". You cant put up with forever. If it gets too much or the boss starts to assert blame on you, it must end, you must speak up with boss. Without either of these things, the toxic person is only digging their own hole. Cheers for the clarity I missed.

Comment: My comment was really for the author, I totally agree with your answer, it really ultimately ends up being a case who the actual toxic person is (which can’t be determined by the information provided)

Answer (score 0):

Your boss has a good point with "[your offended colleague's] truth is her truth".  You (and your boss) don't get to decide what is offensive to someone else.  Don't take your previous boss's support as meaning that what you did/said was not offensive.

Moreover, continuing to use words or behaviors that someone has indicated as offensive is not professional on your part.  Whether you agree with them or not, you need to work to find a better way to express those thoughts.  One occurrence can be explained as inadvertent or unintentional on your part, but repeating it after being told it's offensive removes that possibility.

Answer (score -2):

There are several options here:

1: look for another Job. It's drastic, but I wouldn't accept that from my management team. If I meant no snark or offense, then I won't accept any disciplinary actions over it.

2: Talk with your Boss - this is the most sensible option - cover off why the person who reported the email felt that way *and how you can avoid such issues in the future* - whether that's changing your tone when sending to that person or word choice etc.

3: It's Christmas and so a semi-light hearted option: Use their weapons against them: "well Boss, it's *my* truth that this chat is hurting my feelings and these spurious accusations are harassing to me".

It's super passive-aggressive... but...